# Manim png rendered is cropped

Tags: python, manim

I'm trying to plot a table from numbers upto 100, but when the png is rendered (because there's still no animation), the image is cropped and I don't know if it's necesary to do some zoom out to the scene or what. I tried with the flag -r but it only changes the size of the image, it still looks cropped.

```
from manim import *

class DrawTable(Scene):
   def construct(self):
       N = 100
       ROWS, COLS = 10, 10

       vals = np.arange(1,N+1).reshape(ROWS,COLS)
       table = IntegerTable(
           vals,
           include_outer_lines=True
       )

       self.add(table)
```

And the png:
[image: png rendered]

Comment: how about `table = IntegerTable(...).scale(0.5)` - but it can't automatically scale to screen size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.scale(value)` to manually rescale it.

```
table = table.scale(0.5)
```

[image]

---

If you use `print( dir(table) )` then you can see all functions avaliable for `table` and there is `.scale()` but also `.scale_to_fit_width(width)` and `.scale_to_fit_height(height)` which you can use with `config.frame_width`, `config.frame_height`. But you have to choose which one to use. For some (table and screen) sizes you will need `fit_width` and for others `fit_height`.

```
table = table.scale_to_fit_width(config.frame_width)
```

[image]

```
table = table.scale_to_fit_height(config.frame_height)
```

[image]

---

You can also calculate scale between `table.width` and `config.frame_width`, and scale between `table.height` and `config.frame_height`, and use `min()`  or `max()` to choose correct scale. But again for some (table and screen) sizes you will need `min()` and for others `max().

```
scale_x = config.frame_width/table.width
scale_y = config.frame_height/table.height

scale = min([scale_x, scale_y])

table = table.scale(scale)
```

---

Full code for tests.

Tested with [Manim Community](https://docs.manim.community/en/stable/index.html) `0.12.0`
Not tested with [Original Manim create by 3Blue1Brown](https://3b1b.github.io/manim/index.html)

```
from manim import *

class DrawTable(Scene):

    def construct(self):
    
        #print(config)
        
        N = 100
        ROWS, COLS = 10, 10

        vals = np.arange(1,N+1).reshape(ROWS,COLS)
       
        table = IntegerTable(
            vals,
            include_outer_lines=True
        )

        print("\n".join(dir(table)))  # display all functions 

        # --- manually ---

        #table = table.scale(0.5)

        # --- fit ---

        #print(config.frame_width, config.frame_height)
        
        #table = table.scale_to_fit_width(config.frame_width)
        #table = table.scale_to_fit_height(config.frame_height)
        
        # --- calculate scale ---
        
        print(table.width, table.height)
        
        scale_x = config.frame_width/table.width
        scale_y = config.frame_height/table.height
        scale = min([scale_x, scale_y])
        
        print('scale:', scale_x, scale_y, '->', scale)

        table = table.scale(scale)
        
        # ---
                
        self.add(table)

        # ---

        #self.play(table.animate.scale(2.00))
        #self.play(table.animate.scale(0.25))

        #self.wait(3)
```

Comment: It works great! thank you

Comment: you can mark my answer as accepted and few minutes later you may upvote it.

Comment: Actually I don't know how tho mark as accepted an answer, and I cannot upvote it, it seems that my reputation is not enough to do it:( srry